# Synchronous ajax request manager

Tags: jquery, ajax, request, synchronous

I have several synchronous ajax requests. I want to manage them in such a way that if one fails the rest of the requests should not be performed.

I have achieved this by putting each child request into parent's success event:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someUrl'
}).done(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'someUrl_1'
    }).done(function() {
        alert('we are done');
    });
});
```

but, my intuition is telling me this is not the best solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is totally right what you did over their

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is fine
even better from jQuery Docs

```
var request = $.ajax( url, { dataType: "json" } ),
  chained = request.then(function( data ) {
    return $.ajax( url2, { data: { user: data.userId } } );
  });

chained.done(function( data ) {
  // data retrieved from url2 as provided by the first request
});
```

You can read more about jQuery Then [jQuery Then](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/%22jQuery%20Then%22)